# Left luggage facility for a day in Bengaluru airport

Tags: luggage, bangalore, blr

I am traveling through bengaluru airport on 4th April. But my next flight is on 5th. In between I want to go to puttaparthi and come back. Is there any facility to keep my luggage for 1 day in airport ? And what is the best travel option to go and come back puttaparthi within a day ?

Comment: http://www.bengaluruairport.com/airportInformation/leftluggage.jspx?_afrLoop=10509849573741558&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=87rkeg5sc_4

Answer (score 1):

From the [airport website](http://www.bengaluruairport.com/airportInformation/leftluggage.jspx?_afrLoop=290066380362099&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=rraay2ful_4):

> Kempegowda International Airport, Bengaluru introduces a Left Luggage
>   facility for your convenience. If you are on a short visit or
>   transiting through Bengaluru and do not want to lug your bags around,
>   our left luggage facility provides you with a safe storage option.

Costs vary depending on size, and time, but can be left for up to 5 days.